# Package-private class visible to some other packages (with same name) under a different source folder

Tags: java, package, package-private

When I was doing some testing with packages and package-private classes in Java, I noticed an interesting thing. The following is my projects source structure, the class `MyTestClass.java` in package `com.test.pkg` under source folder `src` is a package-protected class. As per my understanding, this should not be accessible outside this package. But, interestingly `MyTestClass.java` class is accessible in `com.test.pkg` under source folder `test` as well. This happens only if the package names are same, though they are in different source folders.

Can someone tell me why this happens ?

```
TestProject
|
-src
  -com.test.pkg
    -MyTestClass.java
-test
  +com.test.pkg
```

Comment: And why not, it is the same package... Doesn't matter if they are in different directories or jars. It is the same package regardless.

Comment: Thank for the info. If so, what is the use of source of source folders (src, test in this case). Is that just for organizing purpose ?

Comment: @k0der - When you `import` classes, do you inlcude `src` in the class path?. Nope right?. You start from `com.test....`. So, `src` and `test` are at the same level and represent a `global` parent directory. So, the package will be the same.

Comment: That is for organizing only to separate your test and application code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source directory does not matter at all in this case. What is important: the packages names are the same, hence the both classes belong to the same package - everything is correct.

Comment: Thank for the info. If so, what is the use of source of source folders (src, test in this case). Is that just for organizing purpose ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Ussually you keep your actual code in the src folder, and the test classes in the test folder (although both the actual class and the testing class belong in the same package obviosly). If you kept them in the same folder there would be a mess and you would not be able to quicly distinguish test classes from the actual classes.